# In Unity, how to access children component of the prefab using script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Prefab hierarchy:

> Button
>
> > 1 Text
> >
> > 2 Image

I wish to access Image child component of the prefab.

I tried the following code:

```
GameObject addTypeButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
addTypeButton.transform.SetParent(ParentPanel, false);
//set text
addTypeButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text ="Some string";
//get image
WWW www = new WWW("someImagelink");
yield return www;
//set image
addTypeButton.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width,www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
```

However, the above code is accessing Image script of Button (inbuilt).
Not the Image UI component.
How do I access UI Image (child) component?

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## The Cause

[`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) will also return component on the gameObject itself.

> ```
> public Component GetComponentInChildren(Type t);
> ```
>
> Returns the component of Type type **in the GameObject** or any of its children using depth first search.

## Solutions

1. If the index of child GameObject `1 Text` and `2 Image` is fixed. You can get them by [`Transform.GetChild(index)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html).

   ```
   var buttonTransform = addTypeButton.transform;
   var text = buttonTransform.GetChild(0);
   var image = buttonTransform.GetChild(1);
   ```
2. If the order is not fixed, use [`Transform.Find(childName)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html).

   ```
   var buttonTransform = addTypeButton.transform;
   var text = buttonTransform.Find("1 Text");
   var image = buttonTransform.Find("2 Image");
   ```
3. The *safest* solution:

   Drag your prefab to scene and attach a script to your Button `GameObject`:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;
   public class MyButton : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public Text text;
       public Image image;
   }
   ```

   Then drag `1 Text` and `2 Image` to `text` and `image` field in the inspector of the Button.
   [image: how]
   Remember to press apply button and <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> to save that into your prefab.

   In this way you can access the text and image like:

   ```
   var mybutton = addTypeButton.GetComponent<MyButton>();
   mybutton.text.text = "Some string";
   mybutton.image.sprite = Sprite.Create(...);
   ```

Comment: 3 answers but only this one will actually do the job. `GetChild` is better than`Find`.

Comment: I'd add that relying on objects names or hierarchy order may not always be the safest solution. For a more robust one you could use `GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()` and check if the return _Image_s are different than the one on your button (this however will be slower).

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the child object, please make sure that that child object is enabled in prefab before enabling or disabling it after getting instantiated. 
Like in my case, I had a UI Text game object with an image child object. I disabled it in the prefab with the hope to enable it by reference in the script after instantiating it. It only worked if I kept the image(child) component enabled in the prefab.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

`addTypeButton.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width,www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));`

To

`addTypeButton.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width,www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));`